# array in array list

Tags: java, arrays

In the input file, there are 2 columns: 1) stem, 2) affixes. In my coding, i recognise each of the columns as tokens i.e. tokens[1] and tokens[2]. However, for tokens[2] the contents are: ng ny nge

```
stem  affixes
----  -------
nyak  ng ny nge
```

my problem here, how can I declare the contents under tokens[2]? Below are my the snippet of the coding:

```
try {
    FileInputStream fstream2 = new FileInputStream(file2);
    DataInputStream in2 = new DataInputStream(fstream2);
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in2));

    String str2 = "";
    String affixes = " ";

    while ((str2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {

        System.out.println("Original:" + str2);

        tokens = str2.split("\\s");

    if (tokens.length < 4) {
            continue;
        }

    String stem = tokens[1];
    System.out.println("stem is: " + stem);

// here is my point

   affixes = tokens[3].split(" ");
   for (int x=0; x < tokens.length; x++)
    System.out.println("affix is: " + affixes);  

     }  

    in2.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e);
  } //end of try2
```

Comment: Could you post the output of this code? perhaps that would help us answer your question.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve? Do you want tokens[2] to contain an array with each of the affixes as a separate item?

Answer (score 2):

You are using tokens as an array (tokens[1]) and assigning the value of a String.split(" ") to it. So it makes things clear that the type of tokens is a String[] array.

Next,
you are trying to set the value for affixes after splitting tokens[3], we know that tokens[3] is of type String so calling the split function on that string will yield another String[] array.

so the following is wrong because you are creating a String whereas you need String[]

```
String affixes = " ";
```

so the correct type should go like this:

```
String[] affixes = null;
```

then you can go ahead and assign it an array.

```
affixes = tokens[3].split(" ");
```

Comment: it works in term of syntax..however it still consider affixes as one token that consists of ng nge ny..my expectation is ng = token[1], nge=token[2] and ny=token[3].

Comment: Make Affixes as an array. Now the values will be stored as: `affixes[0] = ng, affixes[1] = nge, affixes[2] = ny`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "nyak  ng ny nge";
    MyObject object = new MyObject(line);
    System.out.println("Stem: " + object.stem);
    System.out.println("Affixes: ");
    for (String affix : object.affixes) {
        System.out.println("  " + affix);
    }
}

static class MyObject {
    public final String stem;
    public final String[] affixes;

    public MyObject(String line) {
        String[] stemSplit = line.split(" +", 2);
        stem = stemSplit[0];
        affixes = stemSplit[1].split(" +");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Stem: nyak
Affixes: 
  ng
  ny
  nge
```

Comment: definitely...does the affixes can be consider as one token for each? as i will take 'ng' and check in the other file as well goes to 'ny' and 'nge'.

Comment: Yes, the affixes are stored in String[] affixes, which is a String array of length 3.

Comment: i've tried the coding however still did not working.the affixes only came out with tokens[1]: ng..whereby it considers the other tokens as tokens[1]. since im reading from the input file, is there any syntax that i missing out?

Comment: Is it actually a space character that separates the affixes, or might it be a tab or some other whitespace? Instead of split(" +"), you could try split("\\s+").

Comment: it is only one whitespace that separates the affixes

Comment: while ((str2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {
         System.out.println("\nOriginal:" + str2);     
         tokens = str2.split("\\s");
        if (tokens.length < 4) {
             continue;
            }
        
        String stem = tokens[1];
        System.out.println("stem is: " + stem);
        
       String affix = tokens[3];
        System.out.println("affix is: " + affix);

      affixes = tokens[3].split("\\s");       
   
        for (String aff : affixes) {
                System.out.println("affixes are: " + aff);
            } //end of for
               }

Comment: it works with the regex: affixes = String[] stemSplit = line.split("\t"); and stemSplit[1].split(" "); the regex is based on the format of my input file. thanks for the helps..really appreciate it!